# how to set jLabel with database column value?

Tags: java, sql-server, label

hi im new to coding stuffs and i really want to know how to set jLabel with a data from sql server.
i got some codes but its for table and not Label, also it required us to insert the value first so it can be set. someone please help me.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GUGUNet";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa","gugu");
    String query = "insert into Home.HomeTable (Nama, Durasi, PC)VALUES(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, nama.getText());
    ps.setString(2, (String) homecombo.getSelectedItem());
    ps.setString(3, pc.getText());
    if (nama.getText().trim().matches("[a-z A-Z]+") && pc.getText().trim().matches("[0-9]+") && homecombo.getSelectedItem()!="0")
    {
    ps.executeUpdate();
    
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select ID, Nama From Home.HomeTable");
    etable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    reset();
    //insert();
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Berhasil Disimpan");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Silahkan isi data dengan benar");
    }
```

Comment: Why *not* use `JTable`?

Comment: btw, do you know what `JTable` uses to render its values? Full marks if you said `JLabel`s! Full marks too for using [my software](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/22-resultset-to-tablemodel). There is a button you can press at the bottom of that page ;)

Comment: @g00se i already use JTable, im wondering if i could display something from sql server using JLabel since it will look perfect for my assignment. anyway, im not quite understand about the code so yeah i dont know what JTable uses to render its value :(